# rename the rows with the rows of another dataset of different lenght

Tags: r

I have to rename the rows of the dataset states1 with the names of the rows of the dataset states2, but states2 is of length 50, while states1 of length 51. When using the following line of code I get an error due to the difference in the length.

```
row.names(states1) = states2
```

How could I rename the first 50 rows and leave the last one with the same name, using the other dataframe?

Comment: You can use `rownames(states1) <- rownames(states2)[1:length(rownames(states1))]`, but make sure it makes sense for your data.

Comment: `row.names(states1)[1:50] <-rownames(states2)`

Answer (score 0):

You can try :

```
row.names(states1)[seq(nrow(states2))] = rownames(states2)
```